# How to make this javascript regex to match to comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following regular expression object that matches to the string.

```
var regexp = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
 matchedSearchTerm = $(this).text().match(regexp);
```

How can i make this peace of code to match to the comma also (,) if the string contains in the middle. it is matching to space. OR please suggest if there is another way this can be done

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the regex really "ig"? I think something got chopped off when you copied your code in.

Comment: @siride yes it is, i need the regular expression to match irrespective of the case

Comment: That's all well and good, but there's no actual regular expression here, just the i and g flags. Can you edit your question and put in the actual regular expression?

Comment: -1 for not giving the regex you are currently using.

Answer (score 1):

To make optional rules, use the '?' character:

```
var regexp = new RegExp(searchTerm, "(ig)(\,?)*");
```

Comment: could you pass me the input term? I did my test with "resig,asdasd" and it matches

Comment: You are welcome! Tip: always put some test cases for regex problems. Cheers

Comment: Why does this work? The second parameter to [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is the "flags" parameter (hence "ig"), it isn't supposed to have regex syntax in it. The actual regex pattern is in whatever `searchTerm` is... (Also, doesn't `(\,?)*` mean "zero-or-more cases of zero-or-one comma"? Why not just `\,*` without the question mark?)